# I want to remove the custom error pages and show the errors in laravel

Tags: php, error-handling, laravel-8

I want to remove the custom error pages and show the errors in laravel because I installed a laravel script and I want customizations in it but without showing errors it will be tough for me to make changes in it

Comment: Put the site in debug mode, it won't show the error pages.

Comment: Would you please elobrate in detail what you're trying to do and what you're exepecting?

Comment: Which laravel version are you using